# How to get XML root element attributes using Groovy XmlParser without "double parsing" of XML

Tags: xml, groovy

This simplified code works correctly:

```
    static stringXML = '''<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <ftc:FATCA_OECD xsi:schemaLocation='urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1 FatcaXML_v1.1.xsd' version='1.1' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:sfa='urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v1' xmlns:ftc='urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1'>
    <ftc:MessageSpec>Spec</ftc:MessageSpec>
</ftc:FATCA_OECD>'''
    static void main(args) {
    //NAMESPACE UNAWARE PARSING
        def rep = new XmlParser(false,false).parseText(stringXML)
        def attrMap = rep.attributes()
        attrMap.each {k,v ->
            println "$k, $v"
        }
    //NAMESPACE AWARE PARSING
        rep = new XmlParser().parseText(stringXML)
        def ftc = new groovy.xml.Namespace(attrMap['xmlns:ftc'])
        println rep[ftc.MessageSpec].text()
    }
}
```

And produces following correct output:

xsi:schemaLocation, urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1 FatcaXML_v1.1.xsd

version, 1.1

xmlns:xsi, http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance

xmlns:sfa, urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v1

xmlns:ftc, urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1

Spec

The problem is, that I am already using in quite extensive code Namespace aware parsing and I would like to keep it....

Therefore I would have to use both namespace unaware and namespace aware parsing as in code above

Do you know, how to produce the same result without double parsing the whole .xml (the .xml is quite large) or by extracting just root element of the .xml and than using namespace aware parsing....

Answer (score 0):

normally you have to know the namespace of your xml so the code to take required element could look like this:

```groovy
def stringXML = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <ftc:FATCA_OECD xsi:schemaLocation='urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1 FatcaXML_v1.1.xsd' version='1.1' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:sfa='urn:oecd:ties:stffatcatypes:v1' xmlns:ftc='urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1'>
    <ftc:MessageSpec>Spec</ftc:MessageSpec>
</ftc:FATCA_OECD>"""
def rep = new XmlParser().parseText(stringXML)

def ftc_v1 = new groovy.xml.Namespace('urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1')
println rep[ftc_v1.MessageSpec].text()
```

or you can take the namespace of the root element and access the subelement `MessageSpec` that has the same namespace

```groovy
def ftc_vx = new groovy.xml.Namespace( rep.name().getNamespaceURI() )
println rep[ftc_vx.MessageSpec].text()
```

finally this means that you don't care about namespace and you can use `XmlSlurper` that allows you to access elements ignoring namespaces:

```groovy
rep = new XmlSlurper().parseText(stringXML)
println rep.MessageSpec.text()
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Naturally I know the napespace. The problem is following:

Comment: 1) I read multiple .xmls, which may have namespaces in different versions (see 'urn:oecd:ties:fatca:v1'), therefore I have to read, which version I am processing and based on this use different namespaces... 2)I create groovy objects and process the data 3) I need to create output .xml in namespace which is the same as input one. Therefore I have two option... To have check of namespace version and slightly different code for each version or more generic approach using attributes in map - this is my preferred option